# Mouse Y-Coordinate is opposite from what I'm expecting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this in my update and for some reason, the `x` value works but the `y` is inverted.

```
void Update(){
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)){
        var v3 = Input.mousePosition;
        v3.x = v3.x / Screen.width;
        v3.y = v3.y / Screen.height;
        Debug.Log(v3);
        Emit(v3);
    }
}
```

When I click on top of the screen the emit is on the bottom, and when I click on the bottom of the screen the emit is on top. What formula do I need so the y is at the mouse position.

The x/y values are between 0 and 1.

Here is the debug:

```
Top Click: (0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
Bottom Click: (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

Comment: I bet Unity uses normal coordinate system for mouse coordinates (as opposed to backward one used in Windows windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your debug log shows the correct values. According to [the documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-mousePosition.html):

> The bottom-left of the screen or window is at (0, 0). The top-right of the screen or window is at (Screen.width, Screen.height).

So top click should indeed return `1.0` in the `y` axis. You have to subtract if you want the opposite.

This is indeed a bit confusing, because some things in Unity work the other way. A *Rect* for example, `xMin` and `yMin` are on the top left, so it's the opposite.

Comment: So the question is, what do I need to subtract?

Comment: v3.y = 1f - v3.y / Screen.height;

Comment: haha, I almost had that! I had the `- 1f` at the end and it wasn't working. Thanks!

Comment: I just noticed that when I export it to android it becomes inverted. So I need to check if it is the editor and if it is, I subtract 1, otherwise I don't subtract one... Is that a Unity bug?

Comment: That's strange, it shouldn't behave differently. Isn't it something you are doing in your `Emit()` method?

Comment: Nope, it just sets a `new Vector2(p.x, p.y)` value